# Datepicker function in jquery - External file

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to add the datepicker function and I need it in a separate file, but it seems not to work when I put it in external file even though I linked it, I don't want to put it in the same HTML file inside a  tag. How should I call it

here is what I've done

The jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
}); //enter code here
```

The HTML File:

```
<link href="Styles/StyleSheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery/myJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <label for="Date1"> Entry Date</label>
    <input id="datepicker" />
</body>
```

Comment: Pressumably there's a `head` tag around those scripts and styles? It should work just fine. Open the console and look for errors.

Comment: Yes I included the head tag, the only problem is when I put the js in external file I have no idea why

Comment: And did you open the console ....